# Grep Usage help

Tags: linux, grep, header

I want to use grep to find all of the headers in a corpus, I want to find every thing up to the : and ignore every thing after that. Does anyone know how to do that? (Could I get a complete line of code)

Comment: Could you provide an example of the input and desired output?

Comment: The in put is a list of spam emails with long headers and the output is a file with the headers up to the : like Cc: or To:

Comment: Will post what I had when I get to the cubes

Comment: here is what I had grep -h "^[a-zA-Z]*:" * | sort -u > headers.txt

Comment: list=`echo *`
for file in $ list; do; x=`egrep -n -m 1 "^$" $file | sed's/://'`; head --lines=$x $file | egrep -0 "^[a-zA-Z]*:" | sort -u > $file.header

Answer (score 3):

Use sed or awk.

A sed example:

```
sed -e '/^[^:]*$/d' -e 's/\(.*\):.*/\1/' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is display the first portion of the matched line then you can say

```
grep your_pattern | cut -d: -f 1
```

but if you want to not match against data after the colon, you need a different tool.  There are many tools available `sed`, `awk`, `perl`, `python`, etc.  For instance, the Perl code would look something like this

```
perl -nle '($s) = split /:/; print $s if $s =~ /your_pattern/'
```

or the longer script version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $line = <>) {
    my $substring = split /:/, $line;
    if ($substring =~ /your_pattern/) {
        print "$substring\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(I'm not sure I fully understand your question)

you must use 'grep' AND 'cut', one solution (albeit far from perfect) would be:

$ cat file | grep ':' | cut -f 1 -d ':'

Answer (score 0):

sed -n '/^$/q;/:/{s/:.*/:/;p;}'

This will stop after all the headers are processed.

Edit: a bit improved version:

sed -n '/^$/q;/^[^ :\t]{1,}:/{s/:.*/:/;p;}'